# Is any way to upload image to the webserver using silverlight without using WCF Service

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have a doubt is there any possibilities to upload a image into the web server using silverlight 4.0 and without using wcf Service....

my Question is I want to upload a image into the webserver using silverlight not using WCF....

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/

> Differences from other upload controls
>   Fast! Does not use webservices to
>   upload the file